# What is the precise definition of "Hypergeometric motives over $\mathbb{Q}$"?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, motives, hypergeometric-functions

The question is as in the title, but here is some background:

Section 4 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02900) by Beukers, Cohen and Mellit is called "Hypergeometric motive over $\mathbb{Q}$" but no actual (pure) motive is defined there. The main result of the paper (Theorem 1.5) is the construction of some projective varieties over $\mathbb{Q}$ related to (rational) hypergeometric differential equations and the computation of the number of points of their reductions over finite fields in terms of finite hypergeometric functions. Presumably, the motive (or its realisation...) is supposed to be a (pure) subquotient of the cohomology this variety but this does not seem to have been made precise anywhere in the literature (as far as I can tell.)

In the paper linked above the authors do not claim that the varieties they construct are smooth, but several later authors (e.g., Theorem 19 of this [paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.09026)) claim that they are in fact smooth. Is there a proof of this somewhere in the literature?

Comment: Yes, the motive should be the middle-dimensional cohomology. Beukers-Cohen-Mellit also construct a smooth completion, hence the motive is pure.

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: After the statement of Theorem 1.5, Beukers-Cohen-Mellit explicitly state that the compactifications they construct are not always smooth. Is there some other reference for smoothness, or is it that they were mistaken and their compactifications are in fact smooth?

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: Also, at least when the dimension of the variety is even, the motive cannot be the entire middle cohomology since it will contain Hodge/Tate classes. Is it known that all these classes are algebraic (or absolute Hodge...)?

Comment: I see, I was looking at the preprint version, sorry. And you're right that the motive can break up into several pieces of different weight, examples are given by Roberts and Rodriguez Villegas in "Hypergeometric supercongruences": https://arxiv.org/abs/1803.10834

Comment: Maybe the compactification is a rational homology manifold?

Comment: @FrançoisBrunault: Thanks for the clarification, it explains many of the confusing references I came across! (The decompositions you mention are for a degenerate motive, so perhaps not relevant to the BHM paper where they do not consider such cases.)

Comment: @WillSawin: That would certainly prove purity of the cohomology. Anton Mellit is somewhat active on Mathoverflow and I was hoping that he would comment on this...